# IOException no such file or directory on Android Emulator

Tags: android, file, file-io, ioexception

I've had a look to many stackoverflow's questions but unfortunately, no one of those fit my needs.

I get this Exception:

[image]

The guilty class is this:

```html
public class BitmapSaving {

    private Context context;
    public static File mediaFile;

    private static String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private static Thread threadStoreImage, threadCreateFile;

    public BitmapSaving(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    private Boolean isSDPresent =
            android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    /**
     * Stores the image after taking a picture
     */
    public void storeImage() {
        if(isSDPresent && isExternalStorageWritable()){// Check if SDCard (or internal storage for New Devices) is present
            threadStoreImage = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

                }
            });

            threadStoreImage.run();
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"threadStoreImage.run();");
        }
    }

    private File image = null;

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video
     * @return
     */
    public File createImageFile(){

        // Create an image file name
        threadCreateFile = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
                File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "App_Name");
                try {

                    image = File.createTempFile(
                            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                            storageDir      /* directory */
                    );

                    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
        threadCreateFile.run();
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"threadCreateFile.run();");

        return image;
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The snippet of class from which i Call BitmapSaving:

```html
case R.id.takeAPictureBtn:
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    File photoFile = null;
                    photoFile = new BitmapSaving(getActivity()).createImageFile();

                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                                "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                photoFile);
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA);
                    }
                }
                break;
```

In manifest I've set READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions.

I've also set this in Manifest:

```html
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

And XML file path is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="App_Name"/>
</paths>
```

**It's all OK on my real device (Android 6.0).**

When it comes to the emulator, it crashes with this Exception with every Android version (from 22 to 25) and doesn't trigger the Camera Intent.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you checked run time permission

Comment: which code is there at line 72?

Comment: ' image = File.createTempFile(
imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                            storageDir      /* directory */
                    );

Comment: Yes, I checked all permissions

Comment: @MatPag have you got any solution?

Comment: i think the problem is the value of the property `storageDir`, have you checked that the folder exist and create it if not? have you called mkdir() to create the folder?

Comment: Could you please provide me a snippet of code?

Comment: @GaetanoDati did you find a solution. I'm having the same problem!